# How to make apache camel quartz2 scheduler clustered

Tags: cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have a camel route in my application which gets triggered with a cron expression. I am using camel quartz2 scheduler for this but I am not sure how to make quartz2 clustered as we need to deploy this application on multiple nodes.
Following is the trigger which starts the camel route.

```
from("quartz2://foo?cron=1+1+1+*+*+?&trigger.timeZone=Australia/Melbourne")
```

Can anyone please help me in configuring this in a clustered environment.

I get following when I execute this route:

```
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
   NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support     persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the point - clustered environment? What is the expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved by setting `org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered` to `true`. Here's a quote from [the official documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html):

> Enable clustering by setting the “org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered” property to “true”. Each instance in the cluster should use the same copy of the quartz.properties file. Exceptions of this would be to use properties files that are identical, with the following allowable exceptions: Different thread pool size, and different value for the “org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId” property. Each node in the cluster MUST have a unique instanceId, which is easily done (without needing different properties files) by placing “AUTO” as the value of this property.

To configure this with Camel, you would have to put the `quartz.properties` file in the `src/main/resources/org/quartz`. Alternatively, you can customize the Quartz component and provide a custom properties file or an instance of `Properties`. Have a look at [the official Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html#Quartz2-Configuringquartz.propertiesfile).

Comment: Thanks Milos, I got it.

Comment: I have one more question. is it possible that I can make the scheduler clustered without using database tables

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know of - without the DB, your instances wouldn't be able to synchronize properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are misunderstood 'NOT STARTED' message. The quartz is actually started in your case. Please wait till the time meets your cron expression to start the job/application.
To see the logging setup of quartz, [Visit here.](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html)

Comment: Thanks Jayaraj, I know it is started but it is not started in Clustered mode. I want to start it in a clustered mode. I know I can do that using properties file but I am not able to configure properties file.